# How to expend the code to transfer data from one spreadsheet to another based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very large Excel file from which I transfer complete rows (not copy but cut) to another spreadsheet based on certain criteria.The searched criteria are not only names (string), it can also be numbers that start with e.g. 45*. My created code works fine for smaller files, but for larger ones it just takes too long, sometimes it even crashes.
I would like to extend the code with more functions:

1. Delete all existing tables except the main table.
2. Search for several criteria (e.g. "Government", "Midmarket", "*45*", "Enterprise")  that can occur in column "S" and create a new table for each criterion which were found in column "S" and transfer the complet row in a new sheet. The name of the new sheet should be the name of defined criterion.
3. Show the progress via a status or progress bar.

Here is the code I currently use:

```
Sub VTest()

    Dim LastRow         As Long
    Dim CurrentRow      As Long
    Dim SourceSheetName As String

    SourceSheetName = "InstallBase"                                                 ' <--- Set this to name of the Source sheet
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                              ' Turn ScreenUpdating off to prevent screen flicker

   
    Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(SourceSheetName)                                       ' Add a new sheet after the Source sheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Midmarket"                                                      ' Assign a name to newly created sheet

    Sheets(SourceSheetName).Range("A1:AC1").Copy Sheets("Midmarket").Range("A1:AC1")    ' Copy Header rows from Source sheet to the new sheet

    LastRow = Sheets(SourceSheetName).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row         ' Determine Last used row in column A

    For CurrentRow = LastRow To 2 Step -1                                           ' Start at LastRow and work backwards, row by row, until beginning of data
        If Sheets(SourceSheetName).Range("S" & CurrentRow).Value Like "Midmarket" Then  '   If we encounter a 'Yes' in column S then copy the row to new sheet
            Sheets(SourceSheetName).Rows(CurrentRow).Copy Sheets("Midmarket").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Sheets(SourceSheetName).Rows(CurrentRow).Delete                         '   Delete the row from the Source sheet that contained 'Yes' in column S
        End If
    Next                                                                            ' Continue checking previous row


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True                                               ' Turn ScreenUpdating back on
End Sub
```

The status or progress bar can look like this:
[image]

Comment: Can the sheet be sorted on Column S ?

Comment: Have you tried to run the code without the status bar 'monitoring' the progress? It is most probably a serious 'choking point' in your code. Also, if you only need values instead of values, formats, and formulas, you can vastly improve the performance. Of course, the most critical part is to sort the data as indicated by CDP1802.

Comment: I have not used a progress bar before. It was just an idea to see how far the program has progressed with larger files. @CDP1802, I just tested your code on a smaller file. It works great. I will test it again on Monday on the larger file (over 650 thousand lines). Thank you for the quick support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should only take seconds so the progress bar is unnecessary.

```vb
Sub VTest2()

    Const COL_FILTER = 19 ' S
    Const HDR = "A1:AC1"

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsSrc As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, rng1 As Range
    Dim arCrit, i As Long, lastrow As Long, lastCol As Long
    Dim s As String, grp As String
    Dim r1 As Long, r2 As Long, rCopy As Long
    Dim t0 As Single
    
    arCrit = Array("Northmarket", "Midmarket", "Southmarket", "inside", "outside", "123*")
    
    Dim group As Object
    Set group = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With group
        .Add "Northmarket", "Market"
        .Add "Southmarket", "Market"
        .Add "Midmarket", "Market"
        .Add "outside", "InOutSide"
        .Add "inside", "InOutSide"
    End With
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSrc = wb.Sheets("InstallBase")
    
    Call CreateTestData(wsSrc, 10000, arCrit, COL_FILTER)
    
    ' Delete all existing tables except the main table.
    t0 = Timer
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        If ws.Name <> wsSrc.Name Then
            ws.Delete
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
    ' sort
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With wsSrc
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, COL_FILTER).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
        ' add row counter to preserve order
        For i = 1 To lastrow
           .Cells(i, lastCol + 1) = i
        Next
        With .Sort
           .SortFields.Clear
           .SortFields.Add2 Key:=wsSrc.Cells(1, COL_FILTER), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
            DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange wsSrc.UsedRange
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
                
    End With
            
    ' loop criteria
    For i = LBound(arCrit) To UBound(arCrit)
        s = arCrit(i)
        
        ' use aggregate name for sheet if one
        If group.exists(s) Then
            grp = group(s)
        Else
            grp = s
        End If
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(grp)
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' create sheet or clear existing
        If ws Is Nothing Then
            Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add(after:=wsSrc)
            ws.Name = Replace(grp, "*", "~")
            wsSrc.Range(HDR).Copy ws.Range("A1")
        End If
        rCopy = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
        ' find first match
        Set rng = wsSrc.Columns(COL_FILTER).Find(s, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If rng Is Nothing Then
        Else
            r1 = rng.Row ' first
            ' find last
            Do While rng.Offset(1) Like s
                Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
            Loop
            r2 = rng.Row
            
            Set rng = wsSrc.Range(HDR).Offset(r1 - 1).Resize(r2 - r1 + 1)
            Debug.Print s, r1, r2, r2 - r1, rng.Address
            
            rng.Copy ws.Range("A" & rCopy)
            rCopy = rCopy + rng.Rows.Count
            rng.EntireRow.Delete
            
        End If
        Set ws = Nothing
    Next
    
    ' restore order
     With wsSrc
        With .Sort
           .SortFields.Clear
           .SortFields.Add2 Key:=wsSrc.Cells(1, lastCol + 1), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
            DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange wsSrc.UsedRange
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        .Columns(lastCol + 1).Delete
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox wb.Sheets.Count - 1 & " sheets created", vbInformation, "Took " & Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
    
End Sub

Sub CreateTestData(ws, n, ar, c)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, x, t0 As Single
    t0 = Timer
    ReDim x(1 To n, 1 To 29)
    For j = 1 To 29 'AC
        x(1, j) = "Header " & j
    Next
    For i = 2 To n
        For j = 1 To 29 'AC
           x(i, j) = Split(Cells(i, j).Address(0, 0, xlA1), ":")(0)
        Next
        ' 50% other data
        If Int(Rnd * 2) = 1 Then
            x(i, c) = Replace(ar(Rnd * UBound(ar)), "*", "")
            If IsNumeric(x(i, c)) Then
                x(i, c) = x(i, c) & Format(10000 * Rnd, "00000")
            End If
        Else
            x(i, c) = "Other data"
        End If
    Next
        
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
        .Cells.Clear
        .Range("A1").Resize(n, 29) = x
    End With
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox i - 1 & " rows of test data created", vbInformation, _
          "Took " & Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
End Sub
```

Comment: I have now tested the code on a larger file. Unfortunately, I forgot to mention that my strings or numbers can also contain special characters such as * or x.
Sorry for that! Therefore, a new table can not be created for this type of criteria, because they are not allowed. The code then stops at the following position: ** Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add(after:=wsSrc) ws.Name = s ** 
I think these special characters should be replaced before, right?

Comment: @Gogi Are the `*`'s in the data on the sheet, or just in the list of criteria or both ?

Comment: only in the list of criteria.

Comment: @Gogi I would guess you just need to use `ws.Name = Replace(s,"*","~")` or whichever character you want to replace the * with. If the number criteria have * then you can remove the `If IsNumeric(s) Then s = s & "*"` line.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. How can I summarize the found results like. e.g. arCrit = Array("Midmarket", "Southmarket", "Westmarket","Eastmarket") all in one table? I just tried "market" but it doesn't work. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: @Gogi It doesn't work because the sort will not put them together in the same range, Is this one special case or do you have other aggregations ?. I don't suppose you can change the data to Market- South, Market - West, etc.

Comment: No, I can't change that because the data is always generated that way. There are also other aggregations such as all numbers beginning with "*45 "or strings "outside", "inside" responsibility. Outside and Inside should also be combined in a table, for example. Is there possibly a solution via "Union"?

Comment: OK see update. Configure the dictionary entries with the groupings.

Comment: It works great. Thanks again for your support.